# Sort $_FILES by filename

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

he guys,
as you know, in new HTML5 you can upload multiple files pretty easily.
but what is my problem here is how to sort $_FILES array by column "name"?
here is sample array of $_FILES

```
 Array (
[item_file] => Array (
    [name] => Array (
        [0] => redphotonzillion1.jpg
        [1] => redphotonzillion2.jpg
        [2] => redphotonzillion3.jpg
        [3] => redphotonzillion4.jpg
        [4] => redphotonzillion5.jpg
        [5] => redphotonzillion6.jpg
    )
    [type] => Array (
        [0] => image/jpeg
        [1] => image/jpeg
        [2] => image/jpeg
        [3] => image/jpeg
        [4] => image/jpeg
        [5] => image/jpeg
    )
    [tmp_name] => Array (
        [0] => /var/www/clients/client0/web6/tmp/phpi4i5fE
        [1] => /var/www/clients/client0/web6/tmp/phpzHwagk
        [2] => /var/www/clients/client0/web6/tmp/phpYpAgg0
        [3] => /var/www/clients/client0/web6/tmp/phpAIdngG
        [4] => /var/www/clients/client0/web6/tmp/phpyamugm
        [5] => /var/www/clients/client0/web6/tmp/phpFvWBg2
    )
    [error] => Array (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
    )
    [size] => Array (
        [0] => 7990
        [1] => 8985
        [2] => 8014
        [3] => 7621
        [4] => 7023
        [5] => 7151
    )
)
```

)

all i want is to sort this array by name

Comment: I was also going to ask why... If you need all the info sorted in one structure, I'd probably loop over it and stuff it all into a different array which holds each key in a proper multidimensional way, sub-array per file, then sort _that one_.

Comment: Or maybe copy the `$_FILES['name']` array into another array and sort that one, preserving the keys. You can then still use the numeric keys to access all the necessary bits from `$_FILES` because they haven't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, PHP provides just the right function: [`array_multisort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

It can sort a multi-dimensional array (or multiple flat arrays) by first sorting the first array and then applying the resulting order to all other arrays as well (see [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for examples).

```
array_multisort(
  // Array used to sort + optional parameters
  $_FILES['item_file']['name'], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING

  // All other arrays to be sorted in the same order
  $_FILES['item_file']['type'],
  $_FILES['item_file']['tmp_name'],
  $_FILES['item_file']['error'],
  $_FILES['item_file']['size']
);
```

This aproach will keep all meta information (`type`, `tmp_name`, `error`, `size`) assigned to the corresponding index of the file `name` so it can be used.